# Does Safari on iOS support the attributes max and min for input="date"

Tags: safari

I'm facing an issue that iOS Safari is not working with max and min attributes for input="date".
A google search confirms this.
Even "can i use" page shows a limited support for Safari:

https://caniuse.com/input-datetime

But I still cannot believe it.

Does anyone know if Apple has fixed this issue meanwhile?
Any workaround?